# iOS App Rejected - Metadata Rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I just recently submitted my third app to the app store - I have never been asked for a video to demonstrate the functionality of the app. Is this a new requirement? Also, would recording the app functionality on Quicktime (connected to my device) suffice to meet this requirement?

I am sure they get thousands of apps, but I even provided an intro tutorial about the app works - which would be faster than watching a full demo video. Smh

> We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because
>   we need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use on an iOS
>   device.

Comment: Never heard about this. Do you show some screens in your screenshots that are heard to reach? I think the quickest way is to provide the video otherwise I would ask them what the issue is

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding App Store approval are off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @AzzUrr1 right - no very straight forward app - no difficult screens to get to. This is my 4th app and never been asked for this before. I will make the video hope they don't mind if I use quicktime - so maybe upload it someone where and provide them a link. Ill ask and provide a resolution here later

Comment: I wonder if this is now a mandatory requirement or just a new reviewer that doesn't know what they're doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Quicktime to record your screen. In my team, we recorded app preview video with Quicktime and it is accepted. Also you can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/). And video is required because it gives information to user about your app and Apple says "app preview can help customers better understand your app and encourage more downloads."

Answer (score 0):

What Apple team asks in the review process can be something simpler than an app preview video. They just want a video demonstrating the app, and it will not be used as an app preview in the store.

We had the same issue and after providing them the link to a demo video, the app was accepted.
 
The video was simple: navigating through the main views of the app, clicking the UI elements, basically presenting the app.